How to override --root-dir when starting mock server in IntelliJ?
I want to use WireMock plugin in Idea Intellij Ultimate but I want to make the same folder's structure executable from WireMock standalone, which is:

<ROOT_DIR>/mappings
<ROOT_DIR>/__files

However, when I start server from Intellij, it does not recognize __files folder as --root-dir is overriden:
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1\jbr\bin\java.exe" -jar <HOME_DIR>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2024.1\plugins\wiremock\server\wiremock-standalone-rt.jar --port 8001 --root-dir <HOME_DIR>\AppData\Local\Temp\wiremock-run-8117398651436081273 --disable-banner

Is it possible to override --root-dir so that it points to my project's home?
Edit:
The configuration panel allows only for overriding the port number. Alternatively, you can add some program arguments but when I set --root-dir, it ends up with an error of duplication.


What do you mean when you say "start server from Intellij"? Are you pressing a play button? Is there a place to pass in custom parameter values?

Yes, I am pressing the play button. I have added a screenshot of the configuration that I use so that you can visualize what I am doing.
